# Prove $\text{CorrectSuccintSolver} \in \mathbf{coNP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, co-np

Define the following languages:

> $$
> \text{SUCC-CVAL}=\{(S,x,i) : \substack{S \text{ is a succint representation for circuit } C \\ \text{ and }  C_i(x)=1 \text{ where } C_i \text{ is the i'th gate in } C(x) }  \}
> $$
> $$
> \text{CorrectSuccintSolver} = \{C \, |  \, \forall S,x,i\,C(S,x,i)=1\Leftrightarrow (S,x,i)\in \text{SUCC-CVAL} \}
> $$

I need to prove that $\text{CorrectSuccintSolver} \in \mathbf{coNP}$.

I have tried to far constructing a $\forall$ sentence with a polynomial-time TM $M$ that validates the correctness of the given input circuit $C$, such that
$C\in\text{CorrectSuccintSolver} \textbf{ iff } \, \forall S,x,i\ M(C,S,x,i)$.

We need to check if the circuit $C$ is correct.
The machine $M$ uses the given input circuit $C$ to check whether $C$'s output on gate $i$ is **consistent** with $C$'s outputs for gates $j,k$ that are connected to gate $i$ (w.l.o.g., $i = j \text{ op } k$ where $\text{op}\in{\{\wedge,\vee,\neg}\}$).

I think that there is a problem in my solution (something is missing). In addition, I have few missing details. For example, how to find gates $i,j,k$ only from *succint* representation?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to fix a precise definition of succinct representation of $C$ as $S$. Then you will be able to easily extract the input gates $j$ and $k$ from it. For example if $S$ is a circuit that accepts four inputs $i,j,k \in \{0,1\}^{\log n}$, ${\rm op} \in \{0,1\}^2$ and returns 1 iff $j$ and $k$ are connected to $i$ and $i$ computes operation $\rm{op}$.

Comment: @ArturRiazanov Thank you, that helped! Then I can say $\forall i,j,k$ and now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ArturRiazanov for the help.

The following $\Pi_1=\mathbf{coNP}$ sentence solves the problem:
$$
C\in\text{CorrectSuccintSolver} \quad\textbf{ iff } \quad \forall S,x,i,j,k\ [M(C,S,x,i,j,k)=1]
$$

> The TM $M(C,S,x,i,j,k)$:
> Using the input circuit $C$, checks the following:
>
> - If $i$ is an input gates, checks that the input is consistent with $x$.
> - If $i$ is a logical gate, check whether $C$'s output on gate $i$ is **consistent** with $C$'s outputs for gates $j,k$ that are connected to gate $i$ (w.l.o.g., $i = j \text{ op } k$ where $\text{op}\in{\{\wedge,\vee,\neg}\}$).

Assuming that the *succint circuit* $S$ on input $i,j,k\in\{0,1\}^{\log n}$, $\text{op}\in{\{\wedge,\vee,\neg}\}$ returns 1 iff $j,k$ are connected to $i$ and $i$ computes operation $\text{op}$.

If $C$ is consistent with all of the above, $C$ is correct succint solver as required.